# Git not ignoring files having .classpath and folders

Tags: git, gitignore

My project has lots of nested directories and certain files ending with . e.g .classpath,.properties .
I need to ignore them so I am using pattern 
/.classpath 
however git is not ignoring them and if I am try to ignore a folder using pattern EJBServer/** its not ignoring the folder.I have tried response people have shared for the same issues reported in stackoverflow however its not working

I have attached the git status output.Any help would be appreciated.[image]

Comment: Please show the content of your `.gitignore` file.

Comment: Below is the content of .gitignore file

EJBServer/**
CuramSDEJ/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to ignore 'EJBServer/**' files?

EJBServer/** files status is modified.

That is you already staged this file. Maybe you already commit this files.

```
git rm -r --cached EJBServer/** 
git add EJBServer/**
git commit -m "fixed untracked files"
```

try this.

Comment: If I commit this and then push it will it push EJBServer/.settings/org.eclipse.jdt.core.prefs and other files ?....I just want to track certains files in EJBServer